# Two Countdown timer in same page not working properly (javascript jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Two count down timer button in my html page.When clicked both buttons say, in a 5 seconds gap, it will work but when the first one finished or reached 0 ,the other timer also stops in 5s.

I will put my JS code below.

```js
// JavaScript Document for timer
var InterValObj;
var count = 10;
var curCount;
var code = "";
var codeLength = 6;

function sendMessage() {
  curCount = count;
  var dealType;
  var uid = $("#uid").text();

  $("#btnSendCode").attr("disabled", "true");
  $("#btnSendCode").text(+curCount + "s后重新获取");
  $("#btnSendCode").css('background', '#999');
  InterValObj = window.setInterval(SetRemainTime, 1000);
}

function SetRemainTime() {
  if (curCount == 0) {
    window.clearInterval(InterValObj);
    $("#btnSendCode").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#btnSendCode").text("获取验证码");
    $("#btnSendCode").css('background', '#8d44ad');
    code = "";
  } else {
    curCount--;
    $("#btnSendCode").text(+curCount + "s后重新获取").css('background', '#999');
    console.log(curCount);
  }
}

function sendMessage1() {
  curCount = count;
  var dealType;
  var uid = $("#uid").text();

  $("#btnSendCodeSec").attr("disabled", "true");
  $("#btnSendCodeSec").text(+curCount + "s后重新获取");
  $("#btnSendCodeSec").css({
    "color": "#999",
    "background": "#fff"
  });
  InterValObj = window.setInterval(SetRemainTime1, 1000);
}

function SetRemainTime1() {
  if (curCount == 0) {
    window.clearInterval(InterValObj);
    $("#btnSendCodeSec").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#btnSendCodeSec").text("获取验证码");
    $("#btnSendCodeSec").css({
      "color": "#fff",
      "background": "#ffc343"
    });
  } else {
    curCount--;
    $("#btnSendCodeSec").text(+curCount + "s后重新获取").css({
      "color": "#999",
      "background": "#fff"
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys finally I got the answer.I just modified the codes asked in the questions.

```js
function sendMessage(id1) {
   var InterValObj; 
   var count = 10; 
   var curCount;
   curCount = count;
   
   $(id1).attr("disabled", "true");
   $(id1).text( + curCount + "s后重新获取");
   $(id1).css('background','#999');
   InterValObj = window.setInterval(function(){
  
   if (curCount ===0) {                
    window.clearInterval(InterValObj);
    $(id1).removeAttr("disabled");
    $(id1).text("获取验证码");
    $(id1).css('background','#8d44ad');
   }
   else {
    curCount--;
    $(id1).text( + curCount + "s后重新获取").css('background','#999');
   }
   }, 1000); 
  }
    
    //and called the function on different button clicks
    
    $('#btnSendCode1').click(function() {
      var y= new sendMessage(this);
    });

    $('#btnSendCode2').click(function() {
      var x= new sendMessage(this);
    })
```

Comment: that's a good solution. If you want to reduce your code, you can use $('#btnSendCode1, #btnSendCode2').click(function() { var x = new sendMessage(this); });

Comment: Yes.I wrote like this for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your two timers are using the same functions and affecting the same global vars. You should try creating them as Javascript Object's with private vars.

For example:

```
function Timer(count, code, codeLength, btnId) {
    this.InterValObj = null;
    this.count = count;
    this.curCount = null;
    this.code = code;
    this.codeLength = codeLength;
    this.btnId = btnId;
}

Timer.prototype.sendMessage = function() {
    this.curCount = this.count;
    var dealType;
    var uid = $("#uid").text(), obj = this;
    $(this.btnId).attr("disabled", "true")
        .text(+this.curCount + "s后重新获取")
        .css('background', '#999');
    this.InterValObj = window.setInterval(function() {
        obj.SetRemainTime();
    }, 1000);
}

Timer.prototype.SetRemainTime = function() {
    if (this.curCount == 0) {
        window.clearInterval(this.InterValObj);
        $(this.btnId).removeAttr("disabled")
            .text("获取验证码")
            .css('background', '#8d44ad');
            this.code = "";
    } else {
        this.curCount--;
        $(this.btnId).text(+this.curCount + "s后重新获取").css('background', '#999');
        console.log(this.curCount);
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to instance both timers:

```
var timer1 = new Timer(10, "", 6, "#btnSendCode"),
    timer2 = new Timer(10, "", 6, "#btnSendCode");
```

This is Javascript Object Oriented, look for it.

## EDIT

Your instances won't do anything by itself. You need to use the functions, for example, `timer.sendMessage()` to start your counter. So your event trigger will look like this:

```
$("#yourButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var timer1 = new Timer(10, "", 6, "#btnSendCode"),
        timer2 = new Timer(10, "", 6, "#btnSendCode");
    timer1.sendMessage(); // starts timer1 - also working as a restart
    timer2.sendMessage(); // starts timer2 - also working as a restart
});
```

Everytime you click on *#yourButton* you will call two new instances of Timer and start each counter.

Comment: This one is very good reduces code length. But how can i call this function on buttn click. My code go like this: $('#btnSendCode').click(function( ) {
 var timer1 = new Timer(10, "", 6, "#btnSendCode");
        return false;
});

Comment: Good One @Kiko Garcia . It didin't clicked me for the  first time !!!     this one is working .Cheers .